# Did I correctly Natural join these 3 tables in my relational algebra statement?

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

Can someone tell me I wrote this relational algebra statement correctly according to my query? thanks.

```
SELECT User.uid, Job.JobId, Job.start_time, Job.finish_time, tool.database,   
tool.evalue FROM Job 
INNER JOIN tool ON Job.JobId = tool.JobId 
INNER JOIN User ON Job.uid = User.uid
```

My relational algebra statement is

```
PROJECT User.uid, Job.JobId, Job.start_time, Job.finish_time, tool.database, tool.evalue ((Job NATURAL JOIN tool) NATURAL JOIN User)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that looks correct at first sight.

I'm a little hesitant because you don't give the full schema for your three relations. Possibly there are other attributes; and possibly there are same-named attribs other than the two you're using. If so, the NATURAL JOIN will use those also, which would give a different result compared to the SQL.

BTW re your join: the NAT JOIN operation is associative. To my eye it looks cleaner to go:

```
(Job NATURAL JOIN Tool NATURAL JOIN User)
```